# GridView items clipped and different heights

Tags: java, android, xml, gridview, android-gridview

After creating a GridView, I noticed that some GridView items have a bigger height than others. What needs to be done to ensure that all GridView items are the same height(regardless of screen orientation & different text lengths) + to ensure that GridView content doesn't get clipped?

[image]
[image]

**sw600dp/activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/abslistview_main"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="20dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="20dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**sw600dp/item_abslistview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/cardview_mainitem"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp">
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ripple_background"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/griditem_img"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/griditem_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ArrayList<MainItem> mainArrayList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        AbsListView absListView = findViewById(R.id.abslistview_main);
        settingData();

        ArrayAdapter<MainItem> adapter = new AbsListViewAdapter(this, R.layout.item_abslistview, mainArrayList);
        absListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void settingData() {
        mainArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        mainArrayList.add(new MainItem(R.drawable.ic_info_outline_white, "Fruit and vegetables"));
        mainArrayList.add(new MainItem(R.drawable.ic_info_outline_white, "Potatoes, bread, rice, pasta and other starchy carbohydrates"));
        mainArrayList.add(new MainItem(R.drawable.ic_info_outline_white, "Oils and spreads"));
        mainArrayList.add(new MainItem(R.drawable.ic_info_outline_white, "Dairy and alternatives"));
        mainArrayList.add(new MainItem(R.drawable.ic_info_outline_white, "Beans, pulses, fish, eggs, mint and other proteins"));
        mainArrayList.add(new MainItem(R.drawable.ic_info_outline_white, "More information"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use fixed height instead of wrap_content in the xml of your custom list item.

If you want to show all items of the grid view instead of scrolling behavior, use nested linear layouts with weights, or try  some other layouts.

Answer (score 1):

try this: Change the attribute of the Image view in the file to a specific height of your choice. Thanks
`android:layout_height="50dp"`

That might help in solving the problem. The specified attribute would make it to have a definite height and  remains equal for all items .